# How do you secure in place a polymarble vanity sink/top?

Tags: sink, vanity

Here is the manual for the vanity top/sink https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/VT-SQ19-041217.pdf
Here is the manual for the vanity cabinet https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/19-VW1203WAL-124K3.pdf
Apparently it just sits on top of it. I doubt that connecting the tap to the supply lines and the drain to the plumbing is enough or it is a safe way to do it.
I would have an wall to the left of it and to the right within 1/2" of an inch the shower panel  glass so might not look like a big deal if it moves but it might damage the sink drain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glue it in with silicone - step 10.

[image]

Comment: I am getting blind :-)) thank you!

Comment: It was going to be my answer anyway, as it's pretty much standard practise, but I thought i'd have a flick through the manual to see if they said anything different.

Comment: I was looking for the answer in the sink manual :-)